# Fundamental solution - don’t see why

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation

$$(gV'+fV)'=-\frac{\overline{c}_i}{\varepsilon}g^{1/2}$$
where $(gV'+fV)'=gV''-fV'+f'V$

There are also some boundary conditions given, $V'(v_i^0)=-a_i, V'(v_i^*)=-b_i$, but their context is very long and I dont think I can write it down here.

Moreoever $g(u)=-2\int_{-1}^u f$ and $g'=-2f$.

---

Now, it is said that from this equation and the fact that 
the fundamental solution at s of the equation $gy'+fy=0$ is given by $(g(v)/g(s))^{1/2}$ one can obtain

$$
V=g^{-1/2}\left(\alpha_i+\beta_i\int_0^v g^{-3/2}-\frac{\overline{c}_i}{\varepsilon}\int_0^v\left(g^{-3/2}\int_0^s
g^{1/2}\right)\right)
$$
where $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ are some integration constants which are to be determined by the boundary conditions.

I dont understand what is done here. I am not asking for the exact computation of this formula but I would like to understand what is done here, In particular:

(1) Why considering   $gy'+fy=0$ and why is its fundamental solution given by $(g(v)/g(s))^{1/2}$?

(2) How to get the formula for V then after understanding (1)?

Comment: How do you define _fundamental solution_?

Comment: And what are $g$, $f$, $v$ and $s$?

Comment: You need to give more context :)

Comment: added some context. unfortunately its much context from a paper. but may its now enough context to ask for the procedure.

Comment: The integrals are missing the integration variable. And you forgot to tell that the independent variable is $s$.

Comment: It should be $v$ and $'$ means differentiation with respect to $v$.

Comment: The lack of annotation with variables introduces lot of confusion (in the first place in your mind I guess). F.i., why $g(v)/g(s)$ ??? I won't contribute anymore until you fix this.

Comment: I don’t know why the fundamental solution of the homogeneous problem is claimed to be $(g(v)/g(s))^{1/2}$. That’s why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Integrate once

$$(gV'+fV)'=-\frac{\overline{c}_i}{\varepsilon}g^{1/2}$$

to get

$$gV'+fV=-\frac{\overline{c}_i}{\varepsilon}\int g^{1/2}\,dv+C.$$

This is a linear ODE of the first order, and you start by finding the solution of the homogeneous part,

$$gV'+fV=0$$ or

$$\frac{V'}{V}=-\frac fg,$$ giving

$$V=\frac Dg.$$

Now a particular solution can be obtained by variation of the constant, i.e. setting $V=\dfrac{D(v)}g$ and plugging in the equation.